# JavaScript - iterating through an array for checking condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, highcharts

I am creating a high charts graph that I would like to dynamically give the graph color to depending on the title of an object. I currently have an array `graphData` that has an object `title`.

I have 5 possible results of titles: 
`"LOW", "MEDIUM-LOW", "MEDIUM", "MEDIUM-HIGH", AND "HIGH"`

I am now attempting to iterate through my array and assign a color depending on what title the index has.

My entire graph receives one color based off the last title of the array. I would like the color to effect each index of the array seperartely.

For example: if "MEDIUM-HIGH" is the last title in the array, my entire graph gets `#DD5F0C`

Here is my code:

Array:

```
graphData: [      […]
​
0: Object { title: "LOW", result: 62582 }
​
1: Object { title: "MEDIUM-LOW", result: 57758 }
​
2: Object { title: "LOW", result: 8795 }
​
3: Object { title: "HIGH", result: 262525 }
​
4: Object { title: "MEDIUM-HIGH", result: 167168 }  ]
```

---

```
  let graphColor = ""


        for (i = 0; i < graphData.length; i++) {
            if (graphData[i].title === "LOW") {
                graphColor = "#0D6302"
            } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM-LOW") {
                graphColor = "#0B7070"
            } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM") {
                graphColor = "#DC9603"
            } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM-HIGH") {
                graphColor = "#DD5F0C"
            } else if (graphData[i].title === "HIGH") {
                graphColor = "#C50710"
            }

        }
```

---

HighCharts code :

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: "Bar Graph"
      },
      xAxis: {

      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value + "%";
        },
        title: {
          text: '% of Total'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        reversed: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: `graphData[0].title`,
        color: graphColor,
        data: [graphData[0]],
      }, {
        name: 'graphData[1].title',
        color: graphColor,
        data: [graphData[1]],
        showInLegend: false,
        linkedTo: ":previous"
      }, {
        name: 'graphData[2].title,
        color: graphData[0].title,
        data: [graphData[2]]
      }, {
        name: graphData[3].title,
        color: '#DC9603',
        data: [graphData[3]]
      }, {
        name: graphData[4].title,
        color: graphColor,
        data: [graphData[4]]
      }, {
        name: graphData[5].title,
        color: graphColor,
        data: [graphData[5]]
      }]
    });
```

I am expecting my "color" to be dynamically generated based off of what `graphData.title` equals for that specific index.

Comment: In your first code block you access `.title` on your first check and then `.Title` (capitalized) on your second, third, and so on. They are not equivalent.

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo on my end, they should all but a `.title` lowercase.

Comment: return is going to exit on the very first iteration Really unclear what you are expecting to happen...

Comment: set the color in `graphData[i].color` so that you have a different color per data element. Don't return the color from within the for-loop as that stops it after the first iteration. Then in the `series` use `color: graphData[3].color` (for example).

Comment: @espascrello I edited my question a bit to hopefully clarify what I am having an issue with. I am looping through the entire array and trying to sign each individual index a color based off the the title in the index. For example, `index: 0 === "LOW" ` this index on my graph will show `#0D6302`, next index 1 === "HIGH" this index's data will return "#C50710" and so on

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't completely understand what you mean with the graphData[i].color. Could you write out an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble because you have `graphData.length` number of entries, but only one `graphColor` variable to hold the color. Your code samples don't look complete so I'll make some assumptions about how the surrounding code must be. I recommend building up your `series` data in the for-loop directly so you can just use it in the `Highcharts.chart` call. The code is easier to read that way and probably more flexible too if you need to have more data rows.

```
// build the series data array here so it's simple to use in the chart call
const series = new Array(graphData.length);
for (let i = 0; i < graphData.length; i++) {
  let graphColor = "#000000";  // a default color just in case
  // can use if/else or a switch here
  if (graphData[i].title === "LOW") {
    graphColor = "#0D6302";
  } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM-LOW") {
    graphColor = "#0B7070";
  } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM") {
    graphColor = "#DC9603";
  } else if (graphData[i].title === "MEDIUM-HIGH") {
    graphColor = "#DD5F0C";
  } else if (graphData[i].title === "HIGH") {
    graphColor = "#C50710";
  } 

  series[i] = { 
    name: graphData[i].title,
    color: graphColor,
    data: [graphData[i].result]
  };
}

// Adjust the series data as needed
series[1].showInLegend = false;
series[1].linkedTo = ":previous";

Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: { type: "bar" },
  title: { text: "Bar Graph" },
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value + "%";
    },
    title: { text: "% of Total" }
  },
  legend: { reversed: false },
  plotOptions: { series: { stacking: "normal" } },
  series: series
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've properly understood what are you trying to do, but try this way:

```
const colorMap = { "LOW":"#0D6302",
"MEDIUM-LOW": "#0B7070",
"MEDIUM": "#DC9603",
"MEDIUM-HIGH": "#DD5F0C",
"HIGH":"#C50710"
}

... 

series: [{
    name: `graphData[0].title`,
    color: colorMap[graphData[0].title],
    data: [graphData[0]],
  }, {
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid creating a new array or object to assign the color. I've edited my question to hopefully have it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the Highchart way - you can iterate through the series after chart initialization and set the wanted colors by particular series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6hm4ebna/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this;

        chart.series.forEach(s => {
          console.log(s)
          if (s.name === 'test1') {
            s.update({
              color: 'red'
            })
          }
         else  if (s.name === 'test3') {
            s.update({
              color: 'green'
            })
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

If this wouldn't help please reproduce your attempt with the sample data on the online editor which I could work on.